# How to setOnGoing(false) if CheckBox is unchecked?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-checkbox

I want to setOnGoing on my notification method to false when the CheckBox is unchecked but my code doesn't work. I am new to the notifications on Android but I'm a bit familiar with Android and Java. 
Thanks for the help.
(Had to add detail as StackOverflow asked for it)

Here's my code:

```
package com.arvisapps.lazyscreenshot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

private void showNotification() {
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setContentTitle("Take Screenshot");
    builder.setContentText("");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
    builder.setOngoing(true);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(1, notification);
}

private void dontShowNotification(){
    builder.setOngoing(false);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_1);

    cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked == true) {
                showNotification();
            }

            else if(isChecked == false)
            {
                dontShowNotification();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

Comment: Sorry never-mind i see you want to remove the notification?

Comment: Yes that is what I want but even it doesn't swipe after uncheck.

Comment: Tell me if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this to clear past notifications

```
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nMgr.cancel(notifyId); <-----this integer needs to be the same as the one shown.
```

Just run the same statement but with a false.  It will replace the old notification if you use the same integer.

```
private void dontShowNotification(){
    builder.setOngoing(false);
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setContentTitle("Take Screenshot");
    builder.setContentText("");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

Even better way

```
private void showNotification(boolean b) {
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setContentTitle("Take Screenshot");
    builder.setContentText("");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
    builder.setOngoing(b);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(1, notification);
}

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_1);

    cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            showNotification(isChecked);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: It is working. Can you tell me how to get it removed on uncheck? Thanks

Comment: Its replacing the old notification everytime.  If you change the manager.notify(1, notification); to this manager.notify(2, notification);  it would just make a 2 of them

Comment: Yes, that I know of. What I want to say is, when I check the box, it should show an unremovable notification. But when unchecked, the notification should disappear.

Comment: manager.notify(If the integer that goes here is the same as another that is shown then this will replace it else it will create a new one, notification);

Comment: Oh you just want to remove it? Thats easy

Comment: No, that is not what I wanted to say. I want the notification gone upon unchecking the checkbox. Can you tell me how to do that? (It is unrelated to the posted question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79056/discussion-between-4127157-and-jasz).